# Connect a python-run PostgreSQL database to a flutter web app

Tags: python, postgresql, flutter

I am currently developing a flutter web app for tracking the information in students classes. The app is basically a task management app curated for students.

I have finished most of the flutter UI design, but my main issue now is connecting the web app with my intended database, postgresql . I have come to understand that I cannot connect a flutter web app directly to the postgres database. I plan to use python to run the functionality of the postgres database i.e python scripts to populate tables in the database etc.

The only solution I can think of is creating an API that can take user information from my flutter frontend and store it in my python-run postgres database. How could I achieve this, or what are alternative solutions for connecting the flutter UI to my postgres database?

Answer (score 1):

Connecting a frontend application directly to a database is usually not a good idea. You will expose a lot of security concern within your application. What you are proposing right now is already a good option. Python is a good backend choice for a new project, do explore framework like Flask, FastApi (for creating API), and SqlAlchemy or Sqlmodel (for interacting with your database).